# When can the big blind see the hole hards?

Tags: rules, learning

Suppose we have a 6 players (A-F) playing Texas Hold'em with small blind and big blind and:

1. **A** - dealer for the current round
2. **B** - Small blind
3. **C** - Big blind

Can **C** view their hole cards as soon as they put the big blind in the pot?

Or does **C** have to wait till it is their turn again?

Coz if **C** has to wait till it is their turn again, and anyone from **D, E and F** raises, wouldn't they have to call to see their cards just like the small blind **B**?

Comment: The dealer shouldn't be dealing any cards before the blinds are posted.

Answer (score 1):

you can look at your hole cards whenever you want. I would love to see the backstory that prompted you to ask this question.

Comment: Hahaha yes it was an argument between two friends about the rules of the game...it was about whether the small blind and the big blind are allowed to see the hole cards in the first round, it was quite interesting...alliances were forged and broken on this day...